# How can i notify my android app That user remove it from facebook?

Tags: android, facebook

I have an android app that uses facebook graph api working just fine  . The problem is that , if the user remove my app from his facebook  , the next time i try to use the android app , it does not ask for permission , what makes my app crashs . How can i notify my app that the user have removed it from facebook .. ?

In that case i would ask for permission again to install the app .

Answer (score 0):

Put a try/catch block around the area that might fail, and if it does pop up a [dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html) informing the user of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the application setup page under the Advanced tab, there's a Deauthorize Callback field. If you a specify a path in there, every time a user removes your application, facebook runs that page.

That being said, you can use the page in Deauthorize Callback to remove the user's info from your database. Next time they try to login you check with you DB to see if they're in there or not.

Good luck,

-Roozbeh